# Exposing property of a control inside a WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a usercontrol which has a grid control inside

```
 <UserControl x:Class="MyGrid">
      <Telerik:RadGridView EnableRowVirtualization="false"> 
     </Telerik:RadGridView/>
 </UserControl>
```

How can I expose the EnableRowVirtualization property of the control inside the usercontrol using DependencyProperty so that when someone uses the MyGrid usercontrol,  the user will just do something like this

```
  <grids:MyGrid  EnableRowVirtualization="false"> </grids:MyGrid>
```

UPDATE: Right now, this is just what I came up

```
 public partial class MyGrid //myGrid userControl
 {
    public bool EnableRowVirtualization
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(EnableRowVirtualizationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnableRowVirtualizationProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EnableRowVirtualization.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableRowVirtualizationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EnableRowVirtualization", typeof(bool), typeof(MaxGridView), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnEnableRowVirtualizationPropertyChanged)
     );


    private static void OnEnableRowVirtualizationPropertyChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (RadGridView)depObj;

        if (grid != null)
        {
            grid.EnableRowVirtualization = (bool)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the Telerik grid a name you can then access it from the code of the dependency property. If you also combine that with an PropertyChanged property metadata when you define the dependency property then you can simply relay the value through to the underlying grid.

This is just off the top of my head, but something like this should do the trick:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableRowVirtualizationProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("EnableRowVirtualization"
    , typeof(bool)
    , typeof(MyGrid)
    , new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnEnableRowVirtualizationPropertyChanged) 
    );


private static void OnEnableRowVirtualizationPropertyChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myGrid = depObj as MyGrid;
    if (myGrid != null)
    {
        myGrid.InnerTelerikGrid.EnableRowVirtualization = e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

For more information check out [*DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached Method (String, Type, Type, PropertyMetadata)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597497.aspx) and [*UIPropertyMetadata Constructor (Object, PropertyChangedCallback)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587986.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, can you check my edit above? seems like the OnEnableRowVirtualizationPropertyChanged event never triggerd, I also tried using PropertyMetada but to no avail..

Comment: nevermind, got it working, I just have to access the myGrid inside the OnEnableRowVirtualization        var myGrid= (MyGrid)depObj;
            var grid = myGrid.RadGridView; do the trick